error of not being able to create a workbook for an excel file that contains comments in the sheet when using apache poi
I am using apache poi 3.11. When initializing the workbook of an excel file .xlsm containing comments, the error "org.apache.xmlBeans.xmlException: error: Subsequent sections cannot have content."
How can I create a workbook without deleting comments in the excel file?

That is an ancient version of POI. You are better off using the latest version (5.2.5).

Because there are many common projects using Apache POI 3.11, if you stop updating the version, you will have to fix the source a lot. Is the latest version guaranteed to create a workbook when the file has comments?

Even Apache POI 11 has no problems to create a workbook when the file has comments, just tested. So your problem is not a general problem with Apache POI versions. Thus to help we need a Minimal, Reproducible Example. We need the code to reproduce the exception and the whole stacktrace of the exception.

For security reasons I cannot share more information. However, the source code I am using is WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(new File(pathFile))); Then an exception appears as described. When I delete comments in the excel file, everything works normally

We would need at least the full stacktrace of the exception. Else no help possible due to lack of information ;-).

When I update xmlBeans from 3.0.0 to 5.2.0 and apache poi from 3.11 to 5.2.5, I can read the excel file with comments. Can you tell me what version of xmlBeans library you are using? because I don't want to update the version for apache poi and in the previous comment you said that even version 3.11 has no problem with creating workbooks from excel files. So I'm guessing that the problem is with xmlBeans

when i use lib xmlBeans 5.2.0 and apache poi 3.11 this exception is happening:
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFactory.java:62)
...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFactory.java:60)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlBeans/XmlObject$Factory
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFVMDrawing.read(XSSFVMDrawing.java:107)
...

It is recommended that you use the XMLBeans version that was used to build the POI OOXML schemas. It may be possible to use newer XMLBeans jars but there are no guarantees, especially if the XMLBeans version numbers differ a lot. Apache POI 3.11 fits to xmlbeans 2.6.0. Use a dependency management tool to avoid dependency version mismatch. But you should update as xmlbeans 2.6.0 has known vulnerabilities.
